# Java - How to limit the object creation to only create it using another class

Tags: java

I want to write a class in java that will only allow creating its object from another class

Lets say I have the following

```
public Class Zoo
{
   private Map<String, Animal>
   ....
   getOrCreateAnimal(String name);
}
```

I want to limit my class users to create Animal class only using Zoo.getAnimal() So they will be signed in the map.

Is there a way to limit the - `new Animal()` constructor.

I can probably do it using protected. Is there another way?

Comment: using protected method sounds fine .. are you facing any problem with it?

Comment: Put `Animal` in the same package as `Zoo` and make the constructor package private.

Comment: you can create an inner class in Zoo

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to make your constructor private. Sometimes you might use protected instead but in general private works better. You will need to arrange things so that Zoo gets access to the constructor, for example by making Animal an inner class of Zoo.

This means that the only way to create an instance is through your factory method.

The easiest way to handle this sort of restricted factory access is through putting the factory method in the class itself.

So have a factory method in the Animal class but then have that call the relevant methods in Zoo.

Answer (score 0):

Make your constructor as private and create objects only in your `getOrCreateAnimal` method and while creating the object add it in the Map.

Use `ConcurrentHashMap` to make your implementation scalably - thread safe.

Comment: "create objects only in your getOrCreateAnimal" but it is private

Comment: so what? you can always create objects from the method in your 'own' class, therefore in getOrCreateAnimal you would be able to create an object.

Comment: but inside Zoo.getOrCreateAnimal how will I call new Animal() if animal ctor is private?